# Multiple dashboard messages on my 2004 Volvo S80

Tags: battery, volvo, s80

I am having a problem with my 2004 Volvo S80.

In the mornings when I go to start my car, I get a message *skid service required*. After I mess with it a little bit, the message goes away. I also get a message saying *Immbolizer see manual*. I'm getting a lot of weird messages all of a sudden.

I was told to change my battery to a high voltage. I have a 630 CCA battery but was told to get a 730 CCA. Could that be the problem?

Comment: The problem isn't very clear. What exactly is "skid service"? It sounds like something very specific to your Volvo. Please elaborate.

Comment: Probably says "anti-skid service required", which indicates an ABS or DSA fault on Volvos. You'll need to read the diagnostic codes with VIDA to know what's going on.

Comment: Also, the battery probably has nothing to do with it. It does not give higher voltage, but allows higher current, which should not be related.

Comment: You should be able to goto an auto parts store and have them run a scan on your vehicle for free.  There will be specific codes that they can give you.  If you can get those codes it could be much more revealing and perhaps indicate some bad sensors that you can replace.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a battery with a higher CCA is going to help, but a new battery in and of itself might help. I'd have it tested and see if it's voltage is where it needs to be. If the battery is worn out, you might be seeing the issues you are having. Putting a higher CCA battery will not do anything to improve your situation, unless the one which is in it is lower than it is supposed to be. Even then, a battery with a lower CCA if it's in good shape would not be causing these issues.

Answer (score 1):

From SwedeSpeed: "It can range from a bad speed sensor, ABS sensor, bad yaw sensor, steering wheel position sensor of even a bad DEM."

Scan for fault codes.

Comment: DEM = Differential Electronic Module. I had to look it up.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of "weird" problems seen at once can point to a bad brake module or mother module on these cars. You need someone with VIDA to access modules and read the codes, following the diagnostic flows from [Xemodex's website](http://xemodex.com/us/product/brake-control-module-for-volvo/).